# Simple chat application Crashing when tried to host C#.NET

Tags: c#

When I try to host on my exe (which is supposed to be a simple chat exe)  it gives following error:

**Latest Error**

> 'WindowsFormsApp3.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApp3.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.**

**Existing Code**

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(ServerPorttextBox.Text));
        listener.Start();
        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        STW.AutoFlush = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

After the error the application freezes and crashes.i checked if it hosted when it was not responding but it didn't.
The background workers are there to update the chat.
After further investigation I found out that after

```
client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

'
the program crashed
UPDATE1: After following instructions given it still doesn't want to work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error message is misleading 'Cannot find or open the PDB file' ... Are you sure it has nothing to do with opening that database file?

Comment: What happens when you start it in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find or open the PDB file:

Go to Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and select checkbox "Microsoft Symbol Servers", Visual Studio will download PDBs automatically.

Comment: Didn't work. I don't know what I have done wrong or what could effect it so it crashes